# Como interceptar e cancelar tecla pressionada no IE e firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como interceptar e cancelar tecla pressionada no IE e firefox?
Estou tentando `javascript` puro mas se não tiver jeito pode ser `JQuery`.
Usei o código abaixo mas só funcionou no chrome:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Teste interceptar tecla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="teste" type="text" permitidos="123" onkeypress="tratarPreenchimento(this,event)"/>
        <input type="text" />
        <script>
            function tratarPreenchimento(campo,e) {
                if (isCaracterPermitido(campo,e) === false) {
                    e.returnValue = false;
                }
            }
            function isCaracterPermitido(campo, e) {
                var permitidos = campo.getAttribute('permitidos');
                if(permitidos) {
                    if (permitidos.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toString()) >= 0) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else return true;
            }
        </script>
    </body>`

Achei uma forma:
No html: `onkeypress="return numbersOnly(this, event);"`
No JS:

`function numbersOnly(oToCheckField, oKeyEvent) {
    return oKeyEvent.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(oKeyEvent.charCode));
}`

Mas na verdade queria usar isso em um `eventlistener` de todos os inputs, não funciona nesse código abaixo:

```


    Teste interceptação keypress

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type*="text');
        for (var i = 0;i< inputs.length;++i) {
            inputs[i].addEventListener("keypress",tratarKeypress);
        }
        function tratarKeypress(e){
            console.log('Interceptado');
            return e.charCode === 0 || /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
        }
    })();

</script>
```

```

Comment: Não tem relação com a pergunta, mas deixo aqui [uma pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992115/4056678) sobre criar atributos que não existem, e.g: `permitidos`. Se quer criar atributos customizados, use [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: @renan, valeu, vou dar uma lida.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Teste interceptar tecla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="teste" type="text" permitidos="123" onkeyup="tratarPreenchimento(this,event)"/>
        <script>
            function tratarPreenchimento(a,evento) {
                if(evento.keyCode != 49 && evento.keyCode != 50 && evento.keyCode != 51){
                    a.value = null;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
            function tratarPreenchimento(a,evento) {
                if(evento.keyCode != 49 && evento.keyCode != 50 && evento.keyCode != 51){
                    a.value = null;
                }
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Teste interceptar tecla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="teste" type="text" permitidos="123" onkeyup="tratarPreenchimento(this,event)"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Tente isso o Problema é que se escrever um carácter errado após os certos ele apaga tudo **

Comment: Oi Adriano! Podes explicar melhor a resposta?

Comment: Então, troquei o onkeypress por onkeyup e apago o input se for digitado alguma tecla diferente de 1,2,3 os keycodes respectivos são (49,50,51) o pagar é atribuir nulo. Entendeu?

Comment: Os keycodes se você estiver usando o teclado de números em cima das letras não ao lado, porque os ao lado tem keycodes diferentes, eu acho.

Comment: Podes [edit] a resposta e juntar aí a explicação. Assim outros que vierem vão perceber melhor a tua ideia. Também podias usar `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: @AdrianoCruzdeOliveira, valeu cara, da uma olhada na edição que fiz, achei uma forma interessante, porém não funcionou num listener de todos os inputs que é o que realmente preciso, vacilei em não colocar desde o começo, quis simplificar o problema e solucionou no simples mas não no real.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver dessa forma:

```
(function () {
    document.onkeypress = function (e) {
        //Código para retornar true ou false;
    };
})();
```

Testei no Chrome, Opera, IE e Firefox.